# Excel 2010 late binding on Access 2010 Project

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, late-binding

So i have this typical problem of distributing an Access application to a client. The application is written in Access 2010 and recently i addded some code to export Excel sheets. Therefore i added the excel object library version 14.0.

My clients that run Excel 2007 cannot run the application anymore getting the infamous error: "mssing or broken reference to the file excel exe version 1.7". The question is this:

If i use LateBinding, will the added functionality be available to them ?

I wish to apologise if the question sounds naive but i am new to VBA.

Comment: Yes, late binding should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the functionality should be available, UNLESS you use features that were not available in 2007 (Some table theme formatting using patterns for example is 2010plus) then you should have no issues using late binding.

I guess the easiest is to simply try. Ideal would be to have a virtual PC running Office 2007 and develop using that, when you are targeting client using a lower version than yourself.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This works just fine, thanks. What about PC's who have only installed Access 2010 runtime and use LibreOffice to open reports? I guess in that case the added functionality of exporting workbooks still won't work ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. If they don't have excel installed, you can't automate excel at all (There is nothing to automate).